# How create editable TextView on clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to create a user details page in android app. How can I achieve this:  TextView with a `>` symbol in it, which when clicked create a AlertDialog in it which will be used to edit the text in the TextView.
I can create a alert dialog when the TextView is clicked but how do I bring the shortened text in the TextView with that symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try :**

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
```

In textview in xml.

In Java file click listener :

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(event.getRawX() >= (editComment.getRight() - textView.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    // your action here

                 return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

For arrow you can use vector drawable : keyboard_arrow_right

Answer (score 1):

You can create a layout with an EditText that inputs the new value and returns it to the TextView. **Try the code below:**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />
```

Create a new layout file **prompt.xml**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

   </EditText>
```

Create a new Java Class for the layout

```
public class Editor {
    TextView editview;
    Context con;

    // Param 1 is for the TextView that will be edited by the box
    public  Editor(TextView edit,Context co){
        editview = edit;
        con = co;
    }
    //param message is displayed at the top of the editing box

    public void edit(String message){
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_prompt, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                con);

        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);

        // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

        final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // get user input and set it to result
                                // edit text
                                editview.setText(userInput.getText());   // This line edits the TextView
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }



}
```

Finally, you can edit the value in the TextView by calling the Editor class when the arrow is clicked

```
arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               new Editor (UserNameValue,MainActivity.this).edit("Please Enter Your Username");
            }
        });
```